# MobileFirst 7.1 with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, ibm-mobilefirst

We are going to develop a Xamarin Forms application which needs to be connected with IBM MobileFirst 7.1. I know the available SDK is for MFP 8, Can we use the existing native SDK with Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Hi, i think there is a port already, check [this](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/es/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/xamarin/) o you can create a [binding library](https://medium.com/liferay-mobile/binding-java-and-swift-libraries-for-xamarin-projects-5df4a71f1f10)

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin SDK for MobileFirst 7.1 was previously available through the Xamarin Component Store which has now been discontinued by Microsoft.

The current Xamarin SDK for MobileFirst 8.0 is available as a common SDK for Windows & Xamarin via NuGet. To obtain the MobileFirst 7.1 SDK from IBM, please contact IBM support via a PMR /case.